# Outlining SVG with background color of parent element

Tags: css, material-ui

My goal is to overlap 2 SVGS.
The SVG on top will outline itself to be more easily distinguishable from the bottom SVG.
I'm embedding these on buttons that have transitions/hover colors.
I would like the outline-svg to be the same colour as the button background color.

*I'm using react & material-ui, the Icons and colors are dynamic. I only know those at runtime.*

In essence; I'm trying to maintain readability of both icons.
I think outlining the the svg with itself is a good approach. I'm open to different solutions.
I'm stuck trying to 'inherit' the `background-color` of the button, and set that as the `font-color` of the outline svg AND having that play nicely with the `:hover` transition

```css
.svg-bottom-icon {
  user-select: none;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  fill: currentColor;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  transition: fill 200ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}

.svg-outline-icon {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  fill: currentColor;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  transition: fill 200ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  color: white;
  fill: currentcolor;
  stroke: currentcolor;
  stroke-width: 6;
  font-size: 20px;
  left: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.svg-top-icon {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  */ -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  fill: currentColor;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  -webkit-transition: fill 200ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
  transition: fill 200ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-size: 20px;
  left: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

body {
  font-size: 20px;
}

button.hover,
.button:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgba(189, 189, 189);
  border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
}

.fix .svg-outline-icon {
  color: rgba(189, 189, 189);
}

.button {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  font-family: "Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.02857em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  min-width: 64px;
  padding: 3px 9px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: background-color 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms, box-shadow 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms, border-color 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms, color 250ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
  border: 1px solid rgba(189, 189, 189, 0.5);
  color: #bdbdbd;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  min-width: auto;
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.box {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px dotted #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  example: (hover over this button):
  <button class="button" type="button">
    <div class="root">
        <svg class="svg-bottom-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path d="M15.55 13c.75 0 1.41-.41 1.75-1.03l3.58-6.49c.37-.66-.11-1.48-.87-1.48H5.21l-.94-2H1v2h2l3.6 7.59-1.35 2.44C4.52 15.37 5.48 17 7 17h12v-2H7l1.1-2h7.45zM6.16 6h12.15l-2.76 5H8.53L6.16 6zM7 18c-1.1 0-1.99.9-1.99 2S5.9 22 7 22s2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2zm10 0c-1.1 0-1.99.9-1.99 2s.89 2 1.99 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2z"/>
        </svg>
        <svg class="svg-outline-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"/>
        </svg>
        <svg class="svg-top-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-testid="AddIcon">
            <path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"/>
        </svg>
    </div>
</button>
</div>

<div class="box">
  goal: <br/> this hovered state:
  <button class="button hover" type="button">
    <div class="root">
        <svg class="svg-bottom-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path d="M15.55 13c.75 0 1.41-.41 1.75-1.03l3.58-6.49c.37-.66-.11-1.48-.87-1.48H5.21l-.94-2H1v2h2l3.6 7.59-1.35 2.44C4.52 15.37 5.48 17 7 17h12v-2H7l1.1-2h7.45zM6.16 6h12.15l-2.76 5H8.53L6.16 6zM7 18c-1.1 0-1.99.9-1.99 2S5.9 22 7 22s2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2zm10 0c-1.1 0-1.99.9-1.99 2s.89 2 1.99 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2z"/>
        </svg>
        <svg class="svg-outline-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"/>
        </svg>
        <svg class="svg-top-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-testid="AddIcon">
            <path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"/>
        </svg>
    </div>
</button>
  <br/>
should inherit background color:
  <button class="button hover fix" type="button">
    <div class="root">
        <svg class="svg-bottom-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path d="M15.55 13c.75 0 1.41-.41 1.75-1.03l3.58-6.49c.37-.66-.11-1.48-.87-1.48H5.21l-.94-2H1v2h2l3.6 7.59-1.35 2.44C4.52 15.37 5.48 17 7 17h12v-2H7l1.1-2h7.45zM6.16 6h12.15l-2.76 5H8.53L6.16 6zM7 18c-1.1 0-1.99.9-1.99 2S5.9 22 7 22s2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2zm10 0c-1.1 0-1.99.9-1.99 2s.89 2 1.99 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2z"/>
        </svg>
        <svg class="svg-outline-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"/>
        </svg>
        <svg class="svg-top-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-testid="AddIcon">
            <path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"/>
        </svg>
    </div>
</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`currentColor` refers to the (calculated) value of the `color` property, there is no equivalent to that which would base itself on the background color instead.

But you can specify the *color* for the SVG when the button gets hovered - then *that* will "inherit down" *as* the `currentColor`:

```
.button:hover .svg-outline-icon {
  color: rgba(189, 189, 189);
}
```

(You'll still have to fiddle with the transition settings a bit, because right now they don't change color at the same time with just that modification.)

Comment: Thanks, I'm really looking for a  solution that's agnostic of the parent. I'm trying to avoid having to add css rules for each scenario these stacked icons are used.   I doubt this stacking solution of going to be feasible. I'm better off reworking the svg's to not need to do any stacking.